# Is it possible to catch an Intent or any other kind of "message" in a thread which uses `startActivityForResult`?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I start an activity in a thread via `startActivityForResult()`.
I asked myself if it is possible to catch the returning intent directly in a Thread.
Or do I need to implement an interface and pass a listener between the receiving activity and the thread?

[onAcctivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) seems only to be catched by activities, but maybe there is an other way, maybe not `startActivityForResult()` to achieve this direct connection.

Comment: These are all Main Thread operations only.

Comment: So do you have any suggestion which other way exists to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think starting an activity and receiving a result from a thread is a good idea at all. Whatever your thread is doing, is certainly responsibility enough. The thread should use *any* communication (LiveData, RXJava, Coroutines, Listener/Callback pattern, even Handler messages, whatever you want) to talk back to the coordinator and *owner* of this thread, who will then use a similar mechanism to initiate the activity and ultimately be notified of the "result" which will then talk to the thread. Remember, *separation of concerns*.